# Symfony, adding a new field to an entity for production database

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine, schema, entity

I am trying to add a new field to an existing entity. I edited the entity, the php file, and added the required field.

I run the update command

$app/console doctrine:database:schema --force

From workbench, I see that the new field is added to the table. I cleared the cache using the command

$app/console cache:clear -env = prod --no-debug

When I query the table, all fields are retrieved except the new added one. Also, when I try to create/update the table all fields are updated except the new added one.

Is there any other command I have to run from the console to make Symfony/doctrine recognize the new added file. I am avoiding dropping and creating the database because my application is running in the production mode.

Comment: Post some code that deals with your problem.

Comment: Maybe : php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force ?

Answer (score 1):

Along with adding the new field have you added the getter and setter methods for it??

```
protected $newfield;

public function setNewfield($newfield){
    $this->newfield = $newfield;
}

public function getNewfield(){
    return $this->newfield;
}
```